# Basic reverse formula - trigonometry

Tags: algebra-precalculus

i have this formula for ackermann angles:

$$ SA = \arctan\left(\frac{L}{R}\right)$$

How can i find the inverse formula in the form "$R$ = (...)", to find $R$?

My only idea has been

$$\tan(SA) = \frac{L}{R}$$

but i'm stuck there.

Comment: $R= \frac{L}{\tan(SA)}$

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer! Can you explain how you got the solution?

Comment: Just basic algebra: if $a=\frac{L}{R}$, then $R=\frac{L}{a}$, and let $a=\tan(SA)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

community wiki post so that the question can be closed

You wish to solve the equation 
$$SA = \arctan\left(\frac{L}{R}\right)$$
for $R$.  You took the tangent of both sides of the equation to obtain
$$\tan(SA) = \frac{L}{R}$$
If you now multiply both sides of the equation by $R$, you obtain
$$R\tan(SA) = L$$
Dividing both sides of the equation by $\tan(SA)$ yields
$$R = \frac{L}{\tan(SA)}$$
as @YujieZha stated in the comments.